# Hadoop command line explanation

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-partitioning

Can some one explain me this syntax ,

```
bin/hadoop jar hadoop*examples*.jar wordcount /user/hpuser/testHadoop /user/hpuser/testHadoop-output
```

Why are we using jar soon after bin/hadoop
What does hadoop*examples*.jar means..?
Do wordcount is name of the job, or we asking hadoop to count no of words..?

http://www.michael-noll.com/tutorials/running-hadoop-on-ubuntu-linux-single-node-cluster/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Command Guide](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.0.4/commands_manual.html#jar):

> **jar**
>
> Runs a jar file. Users can bundle their Map Reduce code in a jar
>   file and execute it using this command.
>
> Usage: `hadoop jar <jar> [mainClass] args...`

`jar` is the command. `hadoop*examples*.jar` is the jar file. `WordCount` is the main class. The rest are arguments passed to the [`WordCount.main()`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.cloudera.com/content/repositories/releases/org.apache.hadoop/hadoop-test/0.20.2-cdh3u1/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/WordCount.java#WordCount.main%28java.lang.String%5B%5D%29) function:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
  int res = ToolRunner.run(new Configuration(), new WordCount(), args);
  System.exit(res);
}
```

Comment: hadoop*examples*.jar is a single jar file or multiple jar files

Comment: why do we need SSH access for a new user ; why should it be able to connect to its own user account .

Comment: hadoop*examples* is a single file, the examples use `*` because the actual build artifact (file name) is specific to the build version (eg. `hadoop-examples-1.1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar`). The `*` will match your actual file name. Look into your HADOOP_HOME and you'll find this jar.

Comment: For SSH, ask a different question as is unrelated to your original question.

Comment: tanQ , here is the new post ; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17805431/new-user-ssh-hadoop

Comment: Addendum to what Remus said - hadoop-example.jar also contains other MapReduce programs too like Pi-Estimator, not only the WordCount.