# DiskErrorException on slave machine - Hadoop multinode

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop-streaming, hadoop-plugins, hadoop-partitioning

I am trying to process XML files from hadoop, i got following error on invoking word-count job on XML files .

```
13/07/25 12:39:57 INFO mapred.JobClient: Task Id : attempt_201307251234_0001_m_000008_0, Status : FAILED
Too many fetch-failures
13/07/25 12:39:58 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 99% reduce 0%
13/07/25 12:39:59 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 100% reduce 0%
13/07/25 12:40:56 INFO mapred.JobClient: Task Id : attempt_201307251234_0001_m_000009_0, Status : FAILED
Too many fetch-failures
13/07/25 12:40:58 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 99% reduce 0%
13/07/25 12:40:59 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 100% reduce 0%
13/07/25 12:41:22 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 100% reduce 1%
13/07/25 12:41:57 INFO mapred.JobClient: Task Id : attempt_201307251234_0001_m_000015_0, Status : FAILED
Too many fetch-failures
13/07/25 12:41:58 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 99% reduce 1%
13/07/25 12:41:59 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 100% reduce 1%
13/07/25 12:42:57 INFO mapred.JobClient: Task Id : attempt_201307251234_0001_m_000014_0, Status : FAILED
Too many fetch-failures
13/07/25 12:42:58 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 99% reduce 1%
13/07/25 12:42:59 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 100% reduce 1%
13/07/25 12:43:22 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 100% reduce 2%
```

i observer following error at hadoop-hduser-tasktracker-localhost.localdomain.log file  on slave machine .

```
2013-07-25 12:38:58,124 WARN org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker: getMapOutput(attempt_201307251234_0001_m_000001_0,0) failed :
org.apache.hadoop.util.DiskChecker$DiskErrorException: Could not find taskTracker/hduser/jobcache/job_201307251234_0001/attempt_201307251234_0001_m_000001_0/output/file.out.index in any of the configured local directories
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.LocalDirAllocator$AllocatorPerContext.getLocalPathToRead(LocalDirAllocator.java:429)
```

This works fine when i ran for text files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you have hit this [issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MAPREDUCE-4843). Either apply the patch or download the fixed version, and you should be good to go.

HTH

Comment: i have gone through the link  **Closed upon release of Hadoop 1.2.0.** i am using 1.2.0 only , so can i re-install all the set up with higher version...?@Tariq

Comment: i do got this error in my master task tracker log **2013-07-25 15:23:54,236 ERROR org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker: Caught exception: java.io.IOException: Call to master/192.168.0.1:54311 failed on local exception: java.io.IOException: Connection reset by peer**

Comment: facing this error **2013-07-25 19:41:11,765 WARN org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation: No groups available for user webuser
2013-07-25 19:41:11,778 WARN org.apache.hadoop.security.ShellBasedUnixGroupsMapping: got exception trying to get groups for user webuser
org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ExitCodeException: id: webuser: No such user**

Comment: Sorry, I don't know how did I miss the last comment. Did you notice this : webuser: No such user??

Comment: np:-) Yes this says no such user, how can i comment this..?

Comment: can i replace this web user with my machine user , hduser

Comment: Yes. Replace it in hdfs-site.xml.

Comment: This is the related JIRA - https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HADOOP-5146  . It looks exactly like the your issue, rather than the one I have specified above. But this was fixed long ago. Are you on windows, BTW??

Comment: no i am using fedora, both my machines are of same OS , yes they looks same , but i am using 1.2.0 @ Tariq

Comment: hi Tariq can u please adivse on this @ http://stackoverflow.com/q/17916602/2499617