# Hadoop multinode stepup Connection reset by peer

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

i do got this error in my master task tracker log , Extension to [Hadoop webuser: No such user](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17862787/2499617)

> 2013-07-25 15:23:54,236 ERROR org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker:
>   Caught exception: java.io.IOException: Call to
>   master/192.168.0.1:54311 failed on local exception:
>   java.io.IOException: Connection reset by peer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure JobTracker is running fine, and is running at port 54311. Showing us the TT logs would be helpful. Also, make sure there is no port or any other network related issue.

Comment: Thanks for the check list

Comment: how to test in ubuntu ??