# How to load file from hdfs to local server using putty?

Tags: unix, hadoop

I want to load a file from hdfs to my local server using putty and then rename it and again load it back to hdfs. How can I do so? I need the Unix commands for it. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to copy file from HDFS to the local file system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17837871/how-to-copy-file-from-hdfs-to-the-local-file-system)

Comment: Using Putty would only get it to the server you've SSHd into, not the actual local filesystem...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Copy from HDFS to Local File system.

`bin/hadoop fs -copyToLocal /hdfs/source/path /localfs/destination/path`

Copy from Local to HDFS File System.

`bin/hadoop fs -copyFromLocal /localfs/destination/path /hdfs/source/path`